# error in making skip-layer connection network based on VGG16 in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I am currently reading the paper on 'CMS-RCNN: Contextual Multi-Scale Region-based CNN for Unconstrained Face Detection', it is using the skip-connection to fuse conv3-3, conv4-3 and conv5-3 together, the steps are shown below

Extract the feature maps of the face region (at multiple scales conv3-3, conv4-3, conv5-3) and apply RoI-Pooling to it (i.e. convert to a fixed height and width).
L2-normalize each feature map.
Concatenate the (RoI-pooled and normalized) feature maps of the face (at multiple scales) with each other (creates one tensor).
Apply a 1x1 convolution to the face tensor.
Apply two fully connected layers to the face tensor, creating a vector.

I used the caffe and made a prototxt based on faster-RCNN VGG16 ,  the following parts are added into the original prototxt

```
# roi pooling the conv3-3 layer and L2 normalize it 

layer {
  name: "roi_pool3"
  type: "ROIPooling"
  bottom: "conv3_3"
  bottom: "rois"
  top: "pool3_roi"
  roi_pooling_param {
    pooled_w: 7
    pooled_h: 7
   spatial_scale: 0.25 # 1/4
  }
}

layer {
  name:"roi_pool3_l2norm"
  type:"L2Norm"
  bottom: "pool3_roi"
  top:"pool3_roi"
}

-------------

# roi pooling the conv4-3 layer and L2 normalize it 


layer {
  name: "roi_pool4"
  type: "ROIPooling"
  bottom: "conv4_3"
  bottom: "rois"
  top: "pool4_roi"
  roi_pooling_param {
    pooled_w: 7
    pooled_h: 7
    spatial_scale: 0.125 # 1/8
  }
}

layer {
  name:"roi_pool4_l2norm"
  type:"L2Norm"
  bottom: "pool4_roi"
 top:"pool4_roi"
}

 --------------------------

# roi pooling the conv5-3 layer and L2 normalize it 

layer {
  name: "roi_pool5"
  type: "ROIPooling"
  bottom: "conv5_3"
  bottom: "rois"
  top: "pool5"
  roi_pooling_param {
    pooled_w: 7
    pooled_h: 7
    spatial_scale: 0.0625 # 1/16
  }
}


layer {
  name:"roi_pool5_l2norm"
  type:"L2Norm"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top:"pool5"
}


# concat roi_pool3, roi_pool4, roi_pool5 and apply 1*1 conv


layer {
  name:"roi_concat"
  type: "Concat"
  concat_param {
    axis: 1
  }
  bottom: "pool5"
  bottom: "pool4_roi"
  bottom: "pool3_roi"      
  top:"roi_concat"
}

layer {
  name:"roi_concat_1*1_conv"
  type:"Convolution"
  top:"roi_concat_1*1_conv"
  bottom:"roi_concat"
  param {
   lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler{
                type:"xavier"
    }
        bias_filler{
                type:"constant"        
        }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "fc6"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "roi_concat_1*1_conv"
  top: "fc6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
  }
}
```

during the training, I met such a issue

> ```
> F0616 16:43:02.899025  3712 net.cpp:757] Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'fc6'; shape mismatch.  Source param shape is 1 1 4096 25088 (102760448); target param shape is 4096 10368 (42467328).
> To learn this layer's parameters from scratch rather than copying from a saved net, rename the layer.
> ```

I could find out what goes wrong, I need some help from you if you can spot some problem or explanation.

Really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got is quite clear. You are trying to fine-tune the weights of the layers, but for `"fc6"` layer you have a problem:
The original net you copied the weights from had `"fc6"` layer with input dimension of 10368. On the other hand, your `"fc6"` layer has input dimension of 25088. You *cannot* use the same `W` matrix (aka `param 0` of this layer) if the input dimension is different.

Now that you know the problem, look at the error message again:

> ```
> Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'fc6'; shape mismatch.  
> Source param shape is 1 1 4096 25088 (102760448); 
> target param shape is 4096 10368 (42467328).
> ```

Caffe cannot copy `W` matrix (`param 0`) of `"fc6"` layer, its shape does not match the shape of `W` stored in .caffemodel you are trying to fine tune.

What can you do?
Simply read the next line of the error message:

> ```
> To learn this layer's parameters from scratch rather than copying from a saved net, rename the layer.
> ```

Just rename the layer, and caffe will learn the weights from scratch (only for this layer).